# Apex Batch that Calls a Vlocity Integration Procedure

Tags: batch, vlocity

I have a batch apex that executes a Vlocity integration procedure for every record in the loop.
I'm facing the problem of 'First error: vlocity_cmt:Too many SOQL queries: 201'
Do you have any idea about processing a batch that calls a vlocity integration procedure without exceeding the limits .
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use **VlocityBatchFramework** methods to start scheduled jobs. You can start all jobs, multiple jobs, or a single job. You can also invoke an Integration Procedure or **VlocityOpenInterface** as a job.

> **Note :** my developer org has Vlocity Insurance package, that’s why I will be using vlocity_ins namespace before the class name. You’ll
> need to specify the respective namespace for your package.

The batch framework also enables you to programmatically invoke any Integration Procedure or **VlocityOpenInterface** as a job. The methods for starting batch jobs are as follows:

> vlocity_ins.VlocityBatchFramework.startIntegrationProcedureBatch(String
> integrationProcedureKey, List input, new Map<String, Object>> options);

> vlocity_ins.VlocityBatchFramework.startOpenInterfaceBatch(String
> classMethod, List input, new Map<String, Object> options);

To start an Integration Procedure job from Apex, issue the following command:

> vlocity_ins.VlocityBatchFramework.startIntegrationProcedureBatch({integration
> procedure key}, input list, options map);

For example:

```
vlocity_ins.VlocityBatchFramework.startIntegrationProcedureBatch('VlocityBatchFramework_ValidateAccountBillingStreet', accounts, new Map<String, Object>{'isInputAsList' => true, 'batchSize' => 20});
```

To start an asynchronous Apex job that runs the invokeMethod of a specified class, issue the following command:

> vlocity_ins.VlocityBatchFramework.startOpenInterfaceBatch({ Class name . method
> name }, input list, options map);

For example:

```
vlocity_ins.VlocityBatchFramework.startOpenInterfaceBatch('VlocityBatchFrameworkTestOI4.updateStatus', accounts, new Map<String, Object>{'isInputAsList' => false, 'batchSize' => 20});
```

To chain scheduled jobs that run Integration Procedures, provide the IDs of the jobs and include a chainable option that is set to true:

> vlocity_ins.VlocityBatchFramework.startScheduledJobs(new Map<String, Object>{'vlocityScheduledJobIds' =>
> new List{'JobId', 'JobId2'}, new Map<String,
> Object>{'chainable' => true});

For example:

```
vlocity_ins.VlocityBatchFramework.startScheduledJobs(new Map<String, Object>{'vlocityScheduledJobIds' => new List<String>{'a3Zf4000000T7A1', 'a3Zf4000000T7A6'}}, new Map<String, Object>{'chainable' => true});
```